# How to use a method in another method (ES6 class)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

When I use the work method in the doTasks method, I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'work' of undefined". I don't exactly understand what is going on.

```
class Employee {
    constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.totalWorktime = 0;
  }

  work(worktime) {
    this.totalWorktime += worktime;
  }

  doTasks(tasks){
    tasks.forEach(function(element) {
      this.work(element);
   });
  }
}
```

Comment: use `let $this = this;` above your forEach and use it like this `$this.work`

Comment: This is why we have for...of. To avoid the consequences of having unnecessary callbacks.

Comment: Normally I'd use an arrow function for this

Comment: [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=example) has a 2nd parameter specifically for controlling the value of `this` inside the iterator function. – `tasks.forEach(function () { ... }, this);`

Comment: Most people here recommend the arrow function, which works perfectly in this example. But can you always use them in more complex pieces of code? Or are you better off then with `let $this = this;` as suggested above?

Answer (score 3):

```
doTasks(tasks) {
  tasks.forEach((element) => {
      this.work(element);
  });
}
```

remove the "function" so this is really "this"

Comment: That is another good way! I didn't know that `=>` bound the anonymous function to the class, that is cool to know!

Answer (score 1):

You are in a different closure.
Either use arrow notation (recommended)...

```
doTask(tasks) {
  tasks.forEach((element) => {
    this.work(element);
  });
}
```

...or create a reference to the class instance outside the loop.

```
doTasks(tasks) {
  let that = this;
  tasks.forEach(function(element) {
    that.work(element);
 });
}
```